# How to increase size of table view according to number of rows in table view in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, autosize

I have placed a tableview inside a pane. when i add a list of items in the table due to excessive number of rows a scroll bar appears. I dont want it instead i want tableview to expand itself to view all the rows. This will increase the size of parent pane as well.